# Is there a better way to write this code for the inverse of a direction in rust?

Tags: rust, enums

I'm trying to get the opposite direction of a MovableDirection from this enum:

```rust
enum MovableDirection {
    None,
    Up,
    Down,
    Right,
    Left,
}
```

So the opposite of `MovableDirection::Up` would be `MovableDirection::Down`, and `MovableDirection::Left` would be `MovableDirection::Right`, etc.

I wrote this function for it:

```rust
fn inverse_dir(dir: MovableDirection) -> MovableDirection {
    match dir {
        MovableDirection::Up  => return MovableDirection::Down,
        MovableDirection::Down => return MovableDirection::Up,
        MovableDirection::Left => return MovableDirection::Right,
        MovableDirection::Right => return MovableDirection::Left,
        MovableDirection::None => return MovableDirection::None,
    }
}
```

I'm fine with it's functionality, but I can't help but feel like there's a better, cleaner way to do this. Any help is appreciated and if not that's okay, thank you so much.

Comment: You could omit the `return`s and `use MovableDirection::*` inside of `inverse_dir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really "cleaner" way to do this, but there is several point the raise questioning, one is the style, no need to use return, the other is that `None` look wrong here, you better use [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) instead, to finish you could implement [`Not`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Not.html) trait instead:

```rust
use core::ops::Not;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
enum MovableDirection {
    Up,
    Down,
    Right,
    Left,
}

impl Not for MovableDirection {
    type Output = Self;

    fn not(self) -> Self::Output {
        match self {
            Self::Up => Self::Down,
            Self::Down => Self::Up,
            Self::Left => Self::Right,
            Self::Right => Self::Left,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let up = MovableDirection::Up;
    let down = !up;
    
    let opt = Some(down);
    
    assert_eq!(Some(MovableDirection::Down), opt);
}
```

---

If you wish to keep None, [`Neg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Neg.html) could suit better:

```rust
use core::ops::Neg;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
enum MovableDirection {
    None,
    Up,
    Down,
    Right,
    Left,
}

impl Neg for MovableDirection {
    type Output = Self;

    fn neg(self) -> Self::Output {
        match self {
            Self::None => Self::None,
            Self::Up => Self::Down,
            Self::Down => Self::Up,
            Self::Left => Self::Right,
            Self::Right => Self::Left,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(MovableDirection::Down, -MovableDirection::Up);
    assert_eq!(MovableDirection::None, -MovableDirection::None);
}
```

Comment: How about `Neg` instead of `Not`?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a little more verbose than it needs to be, which Clippy would point out as:

```
warning: unneeded `return` statement
  --> src/lib.rs:11:34
   |
11 |         MovableDirection::Up  => return MovableDirection::Down,
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#needless_return
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::needless_return)]` on by default
   = help: remove `return`
```

Everything is an expression in Rust, and the last expression in a function body is returned. You only need the `return` keyword for early return. So you can follow Clippy's advice and rewrite it like this:

```
fn inverse_dir(dir: MovableDirection) -> MovableDirection {
    use MovableDirection::*;
    match dir {
        Up => Down,
        Down => Up,
        Left => Right,
        Right => Left,
        None => None,
    }
}
```

There really can't be a much shorter way of writing this. There is nothing about the `enum` that intrinsically encodes these relationships. You must *somehow* write down a mapping from each variant to its opposite, and that's likely to take a line per mapping.

---

As a more general comment, you might consider removing the `None` variant and using an `Option<MovableDirection>` instead. This will have no runtime overhead compared to what you've got, and will let you ignore the `None` variant in places where it isn't needed. You'll also get all of `Option`'s methods and trait implementations for free.